# Kriging results in log mode and SpatialPointsDataFrame manipulation

Tags: raster, kriging, log

I've a little problem, probably because I'm not fully expert with R data manipulation. 
I've perfomed a kriging elaboration of mydata, in log mode, as the classical meuse example, but how can I export a grid in real data ?
I.e. from previous idw map I've used this simple statement:
idw = idw(Var~1,mydata,grd,idp=2)
write.asciigrid(idw,"Var IDW.asc")

Unfortunately, Qgis not perform, actually, the "exp" function, I've found also the R calc utility of raster package but it doesn't apply to SpatialPoinsDataFrame, it seems ...
fun =function(x) {exp(x)} 
krg_exp = calc(krg,fun)
*Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"SpatialPointsDataFrame", "function"’*

Can you help me ?